# how to integrate non separable equation in initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(3x^2y^2-y^3+2x)\ dx + (2x^3y-3xy^2+1)\ dy=0$$

I have tried integrating this by parts but somewhere it became very messy and I couldn't continue it.

I am new to this and I don't know how to right proper equation in the text so please bear with me.

Comment: Ya , but was unable to apply in the question :(

Answer (score 1):

This is simple ODE with total differential.

In this case we have:

$$P(x,y) = 3x^2y^2 - y^3 + 2x$$

$$Q(x,y) = 2x^3y - 3xy^2 + 1$$

and partial derivate of each function is

$$\frac{dP}{dy} = 6x^2y - 3y^2$$

$$\frac{dQ}{dx} = 6*x*x*y - 3*y*y$$

So we obtain $$\frac{dP}{dy} =\frac{dQ}{dx}$$

Now you only need to apply formula for calculating ODE with total differential.

Hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

What is $d(x^3y^2)$?

What is $d(xy^3)$?

Spoilers below. Hover to see.

> $d(x^3y^2)-d(xy^2)+d(x^2)+dy=0$

Answer (score 0):

This is an exact differential equation.
$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (2x^3y−3xy^2+1) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (3x^2y^2−y^3+2x) = 6x^2y-3y^2$

Answer is straightforward:
$$x^3y^2-xy^3+y+x^2 = c$$

Look up "Exact differential equations", if you still have a problem with these type of questions